# Перегруппировка массива по ключевому параметру?

Tags: php, массивы

Например есть такой массив:

```
    $arr = array(
        array('id'=>0,'name'=>'Victor','Car'=>'Ford'),
        array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Alex','Car'=>'Mercedes'),
        array('id'=>2,'name'=>'Max','Car'=>'Ford'),
        array('id'=>3,'name'=>'Jon','Car'=>'Mercedes'),
        array('id'=>4,'name'=>'Andrew','Car'=>'Toyota'),
        array('id'=>5,'name'=>'Stas','Car'=>'')
    );
```

Распечатку не буду выводить, суть в том чтобы с этого массива сделать новый, только ключами будут машины, напр.

```
['Ford'] = array пользователей у которых форд
```

Собственно все, мои попытки:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach( $arr as $val )
{
    foreach( $arr as $value)
    {
        if( $val['Car'] == $value['Car'] )
        {
            $new_array[$val['Car']][] = array('id'=>$value['id'],'name'=>$value['name']);
        }       
    }   
}
```

Увы, каким-то я неправильным путем пошел видимо, нужна помощь, хотя бы совет.

п.с. есть пользователи у которых вообще нет машины как видно, им тоже нужна отдельная группа в том же массиве, только я не знаю без ключа получается.

**Решилось** так:

```
$new = array();

foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
 $new[$value['Car']][] = $arr[$key];
}
```

Comment: На C# было бы

    array.GroupBy(v => v.Car).ToDictionary(g => g.Key);

Comment: круто! Люблю C#. Увы, не C# сейчас актуален.

Comment: @Maris: LINQ -- лишь отражение мощи силы^W функционального программирования.

Comment: Сам догнал.

Comment: Вам не нужен ключ в цикле, значение сохраняется в ``$value``, т.е.:

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $new[$value['Car']][] = $value;
    }

Comment: Без разницы, в принципе он не сильно мешает.

Answer (score 1):

Всё куда проще:

1. Объявили пустой массив
2. Обходим первоначальный массив (`$arr`) и делаем `$new[$value['Car']][] = $value;`

В общем, ваша попытка была правильной, за исключением двух вложенных циклов. Зачем?

Comment: @xEdelweiss, $new = array();

foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
 $new[$key][] = $value;
}

Неужели это имелось в виду?

Comment: Ох я и облажался. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант ([смотреть в действии](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d4k-evw)):

```
$cars = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    $key = array_pop($arr[$i]);
    // $key = end($arr[$i]); // для второго варианта
    $cars[$key ? $key : 'no_car'] = $arr[$i];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($cars);
echo '</pre>';
// результат
Array
(
    [Ford] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Max
        )

    [Mercedes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Jon
        )

    [Toyota] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Andrew
        )

    [no_car] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Stas
        )

)
```

Если не нужно вырезать елемент с названием машины, то [использовать **end()**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bz9-suz)